# Using Ajax to get part of a site and implementing it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering if I could somehow get the currency converter along with its functionality from the site http://www.preev.com/

I tried downloading the page and using ajax to get just that part and I did get that part but it was not functioning. So I was hoping there could some way to get the currency converter on my site along with its functionality. You must use jquery's get() or post() or load() ajax function codes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scraping of the site why don't you use the same service?

Provided by the Mt.Gox Trade API: https://mtgox.com/api ?

I image http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker is just what you're looking for.

Comment: forget that i am talking about preev.com,

Comment: Is there anyway to get part of a site along with its functioality with jquery ajax

Comment: I just need to know if it can be done. Thanks

Comment: It should be possible. There is an JavaScript interface, so simply request the currency conversion rate and do some math

Comment: i have done so using ajax but there is no functionality of the converter and I just found out it is not a currency converter. If you want you can also suggest some php codes.